# How Can I rotate the Android TextView as merge cell

Tags: android, textview, rotation

Here is my `LinerLayout`, I have tried many times to rotation the `TextView` as I want, however, neither  `width` nor the `gravity` worked as expectation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/divider"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:text="11111111111111111111111111"
        android:translationY="-100dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/color_blue" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/divider"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:text="Hello TextView Demos"
        android:translationY="100dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTE**:

1. `LinearLayout`'s width Must be `50dp`

[image: Here is the screenshot in Android Studio]

Comment: i dont understand you need portrait? or landscape design  or what do you mean please ellaborate

Comment: portrait , and the direction of the text is bottom to top.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/divider"
        android:text="11111111111111111111111111"
        android:translationY="-100dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/color_blue" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/divider"
        android:text="Hello TextView Demos"
        android:translationY="100dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```